# TemplateDoesNotExist at /admin/MY_APP/my_model/ reversion/change_list.html

Tags: python, django

I update a old 1.3 django site to 1.8.

The predecessor developer used django-reversion to save each change in the models.

The problem he override the admin template for some model and I get this error for ALL models:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /admin/MY_APP/my_model/

reversion/change_list.html
```

I found this [link](http://quabr.com/33611983/conflict-with-django-reversion-package-while-adding-custom-button-in-django-admi) in google.

So I change the path in my template directory like this:

/reversion/MY_APP/ instead /admin/MY_APP

Unfortunately, this don't solve the problem.

NB: The application name is in uppercase

Comment: When you changed the location what error did you get? Also, why `my_model`?

Comment: It's the same error. my_model is just a generic term. It's my model that i created.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm just stupid. I forgot to add 'reversion' to INSTALLED_APPS.

Answer (score 0):

THX for your answer, but I can't vote for you without 15 reputation.

add to INSTALLED_APPS.

First, I used django 1.8 and django-import-export==0.2.2, and they do not match well, and I updated to django-import-export==0.4.5